# Etimología de "cortapisa"

Tags: etimología

> Uno no entiende por qué en el Senado los parlamentarios colocaron tantas **cortapisas** al avance del proyecto si lo que estamos haciendo a través de él es lo que se hace en otros órganos de protección de los derechos de los ciudadanos...

> Català
> Pronúncia(i): oriental /kur.təˈpi.zə/, occidental /koɾ.taˈpi.za/
> Rimes: -iza
> Etimologia: Del llatí culcita pinsa, «vànova embastada o guarnida»

Nunca me han dejado conformes este tipo de referencias en relación a su orígen:

> Muy fácil. **Cortapisa** es tanto como la restricción o limitación para ejercer una determinada acción. **Primitivamente la “cortapisa” era una guarnición que se ponía a ciertas prendas de vestido. De ahí procede el sentido de algo añadido que puede ser un estorbo.**

> Tesoro de la Lengua Castellana o Española, Sebastián de Covarrubias y Orozco
> Cortapisa , guarnicion sequatur hortari soleat , seu quod ipsa . cortada y sobrepuesta . fe mutuo frequenter ad pugnam hora CORTAR , [ cindere , secare ...

> Studies in Historical Ibero-Romance Morpho-Syntax
> For example, according to Corominas and Pascual (1980-1991) cortapisa 'limitation', lit. 'cut-tread' [ad 1435], formely 'adornment on clothes', comes from Old Catalan **cortapisa** 'id'., possibly meaning 'adornment of different material sewn on bedcovers', in turn from Lat. culcita pinsa 'pleated mattress'.

Para mí, es algo como esto:

> DICCIONARIO ETIMOLÓGICO VASCO
> IPHULAR2 BN, L, ipular G 'tierra que queda sin labrar en el borde de los campos
> labrados', G 'trecho' ipura Leon la primera acepcion, AN '**cortapisa**'. Cf.
> ip(h)uru N 'borde baldio de un campo' e iphuru-belhar mencionado supra.

> Baldío, baldía
> 2. adjetivo
> [esfuerzo, empeño] Que resulta inútil porque no ofrece ningún resultado.
> "todo esfuerzo se había demostrado al final baldío"

> iphuru
> Bordura de campo. De idi "buey" y buru "bordura".
> Chaintre, bout du champ. De idi "boeuf" et buru "bout".
> Field’s edge or end. From idi "oxes" and buru "end".

¿Alguien tiene más información sobre lo que aparece en este diccionario vasco, o sobre si relamente era un estorbo en la vestimenta(catalán)? Porque siempre me he pensado que tiene alguna relación con un terreno que no permite el avance o lo ralentiza.

Comment: @今夜九 qué es PIE, indoeuropeo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corominas lo tiene bastante claro: proviene del latín "culcita pinsa". Según sus estudios, esta palabra aparece en su documentación por primera vez hacia 1438, con el sentido de "guarnición de tela diferente, que se ponía a ciertas prendas de vestir".

La evolución semántica fue posterior. Cervantes usa el término como sinónimo de añadidura (cita: "Teresa me pusieron [...] sin añadiduras ni cortapisas"), pero no fue hasta más tarde que ese significado se concretó en el de "condición o restricción con que se concede o se posee una cosa".

Answer (score 1):

---

- La expresión "cortapisa", es una palabra compuesta que se refiere a dos verbos cortar y pisar que van de forma conjunta, con el sentido de obstáculo, más que un adorno de ropa.
- Según lo que tengo entendido el término procede de las más antiguas imprentas ó de los trabajos realizados en las imprentas, cuando las antiguas máquinas realizaban solo una parte del trabajo y otra era completamente manual. Dentro de estas actividades, algunas consistían en doblar y cortar los pliegos que se utilizaban de forma habitual, mientras que otras  se dedicaban a entablillar y coser los futuros panfletos, ejemplares, libros...
  Por tanto, los pliegos mientras se dejaban descansar, antes de comenzar otra actividad, se les solía poner encima una pieza, normalmente de metal, con cierto peso, que impedía que los pliegos pudieran volar ó perderse, es decir, los papeles eran *pisados* con un objeto.
- A la acción conjunta, cortar y pisar, de primero, "cortar" y luego "pisar" con un obstáculo que *"impedia"* la perdida de esos papeles, dio y *sirvio* para expresar cualquier tipo de estorbo, dificultad, traba...en la voz "cortapisa".

Espero haya servido. Saludos.
Diego M.

Comment: Sí, encontré un texto de imprentas antiguas pero usaba incluso ahí cortapisa como inconveniente. Sí todo es cierto, es muy interesante.